# entity framework 6.1.2 startup time

Tags: entity-framework-6

Very first query to dbcontext takes very long time. I did some search and found that for the first call there is metadata calculation which takes time. Solution suggested was to use entity framework powertools to generate pre complied views. I tried this but is was of no use.

Did anyone get any solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using Code First? http://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/

Comment: Yes. We have already set initilizer to null. Database.SetInitializer<CARAContext>(null);